# Multiple Var Values - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following which works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on("change", function() {
            var blueTicked = jQuery('input[id="help_completing_form1"]');
            var blueTickedParent = jQuery(blueTicked).parents('.master-field');
            var blueTickedParentSiblingMessage = jQuery(blueTickedParent).next('.eb-message');
            if((blueTicked).is(':checked')) {
                blueTickedParent.addClass('blue-condition');
                blueTickedParentSiblingMessage.addClass('blue-condition');
            }else {jQuery('.master-field').removeClass('blue-condition');}

    });
});
```

However I would like to add multiple values to the variable:

```
var blueTicked
```

So it would read something like:

```
var blueTicked =  jQuery('input[id="help_completing_form1"]'), jQuery('input[id="bloodpressure2"]'));
```

Is this possible? I dont seem to be able to get my head round it.

Comment: do you want it to be a concatenated string or an array ? Or just an object? W

Comment: From the looks of it you just to use an array.

Comment: Also, maybe use a class so you could select them both using that class as a selector?

Comment: `jQuery('input[id="help_completing_form1"]')` is an expensive way for `jQuery('#help_completing_form1')`

Comment: How do you plan on referencing individual items in your variable?  That will largely dictate what would be best to use (array, object, etc.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? At the minute your code is going to run when the `change` event is raised on any input, is that what you want?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Use array. 

Then 

`arr.join(",");`

Comment: Array join what @DeepakKamat ?

Comment: From your code @ADRIAN I guess you've something like https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/3wnyc9kg/1/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki When you tagged ADRIAN it actually tagged me lol.

Comment: hhhhh sorry man

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to give your elements `#help_completing_form1 & #bloodpressure2` a common class and select the both using the class selector like :

```
var blueTicked = jQuery('.common-class');
```

HTML should be something like :

```
<input id="help_completing_form1" class="common-class">
<input id="bloodpressure2" class="common-class">
```

Comment: If this is the only change than this may break the change handler if each input has its own `.master-field`

Comment: Since he want to store multiple element then he should think to adjust the event.